# Cannot insert data in SQL table when using the same code as previous query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert two pieces of data into two different tables. It successfully does it with one of the tables but not the second. I have used or die mysqli_error to see if it will tell me the error, but it does not show anything. See the code below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ticketUsers 
            (name, emailAddress, password) 
            SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$name', '$emailAddress', '$dbPassword') AS tmp
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                                SELECT name 
                                FROM ticketUsers 
                                WHERE emailAddress = '$emailAddress'
                            ) 
            LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if($query)
{
    echo "Success entering ticket Users";
}
else if(!$result)
{
   echo "Cant enter information";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO tickets 
                (id, emailAddress, urgency, subject, 
                 description, relevantURL, status) 
        VALUES ('$id', '$emailAddress', '$username', '$urgency', 
                '$subject', '$description2', '$relevantURL', 'Open')";

$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if($query)
{
    echo "Success entering tickts";
}
else if(!$result)
{
   echo "Cant enter information";
}

if (!sql) 
{
echo "There has been an error creating your ticket.";
}
```

Comment: Check for errors, the real error.

Comment: Also look at prepared parameterized queries

Comment: Put a breakpoint and try to debug. See values are passed or not.

Comment: What is the value for the first query?

Comment: The first query works fine and prints the Success entering ticket users

Comment: Had you done what I told you at first, you would have been told about the syntax error you made.

Comment: Does that first query actually store a new row? With correct data?

Comment: You should also look at running this is a transaction

Comment: You're also open to an sql injection. Sure hoping this isn't a live site (yet). That's given what you posted for code.

Comment: Nope not a live site.

Comment: Also it is not the entire file. Obviously if the PHP file had just what I posted in it, it would not work and would be pretty clear why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query, you try to insert in a table with 7 fields 8 values.

I think you don't want to insert '$username' in the query.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. Thank you that fixed it!